# Oozie > ssh action > how to add ssh options

Tags: ssh, oozie

I am trying to use Oozie ssh action to copy files from a local directory to a remote server. The main problem is that I am using a private key, so I have to use the `-i` option to define the private key. But the Oozie ssh action does not have the option node, which I can define the `-i` option.

Is there any workaround for this? Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? How does your workflow node look like right now?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32249837/using-oozie-ssh-action-with-private-key/